# Is it possible to unregister jersey component?

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

Dropwizard registers jersey component `A`. I want to replace this component with my custom version. Is it possible?

Comment: what is a jersey component??

Comment: may be it's called `features` - `MessageBodyReader`s, `Filter`s, etc

Comment: Is there a specific component you are talking about?

Comment: Dropwizard registered `MessageBodyReader` (`JacksonMessageBodyProvider`). I wanna replace it with my custom implementation

Answer (score 2):

from the docs:

https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#providers-selection

This means:

If you have a custom provider, your custom provider will be used.

By example:

Say I have a user class:

```
public class User {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    
    @JsonProperty("password")
    private String password;
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

We have a resource returning the User:

```
@Path("/hello/world2")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MsgBodyWriterTest {

    @GET
    @Path("/v1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User test() {
        User u = new User();
        u.setName("Test");
        return u;
    }
}
```

And we have a MessageBodyWriter that deals with this User object:

```
@Provider
public class UserMsgBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<User> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == User.class;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(User t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(User t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        System.out.println("Use custom Provider");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(entityStream, t);
    }

}
```

We then hook things together in the main by registering the resource and the provider:

```
public class Starter extends Application<Configuration> {

    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        environment.jersey().register(MsgBodyWriterTest.class);
        environment.jersey().register(UserMsgBodyWriter.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Starter().run("server", "/Users/artur/dev/repo/dw-test/src/main/resources/configuration.yaml");
    }
    
}
```

When started, it will publish the jersey resource, and we can then access it:

```
arturk:~ artur$ curl -XGET  "localhost:9085/hello/world2/v1"
```

This will then log:

```
Use custom Provider
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [02/Jun/2016:09:21:31 +0000] "GET /hello/world2/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 31 "-" "curl/7.43.0" 30
```

Note the output: "Use custom Provider". This is simply to demonstrate that the right provider has been called.

I hope this is what your looking for.

In short, the default provider that is hooked in comes from Jaxb. it deals with all json types and enables default beans serialising. Without it, your json will not know how to be parsed. You don't want to get rid of it, but rather add to it.
By creating your own provider, the selection will take care of choosing the right thing for you. By default, jersey will sort custom providers before default providers. So as long as your isWriteable() method is implemented correctly, your provider will be chosen to do the work.

EDIT:

to answer your actual question. If you MUST get rid of the DW registered provider, there is a way for that too. You will have to overwrite the default server factory. Look at:

AbstractServerFactory#createAppServlet. This is where the default providers are hooked in. Again though, if you simply register your own, the default will never be used and you'll save yourself the work of creating a server factory (which is also fairly easy and straight forward in case you want to).

Cheers,

Artur

Comment: Updated link to documentation:
https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#providers-selection

Comment: Cheers! Updated the link in the post as well

Comment: Note the documentation has moved again: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#providers-selection